# Why is this combination of TabControl - DataTrigger - Storyboard not working?

Tags: wpf, storyboard, tabcontrol, datatrigger

I've encountered some kind of binding error in my program, which I can't explain by myself.

I wanted to style a `TextBox`, so that it displays a warning icon if the value is not covered by some product specification. When the user hovers the cursor over the icon, a more detailed warning message should appear in an `AdornerLayer`.

[image: Screenshot of the application]

As you can see, the control works, but I still have a question about it. To describe my problem, I have reduced the code to its absolute minimum:

### My code

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication3.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:ThemesAero="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="22" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ThemesAero:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ThemesAero:ListBoxChrome>
                            <Image Name="WarningIcon" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="warning_256x256.png" />
                            <Border x:Name="InformationBorder" Background="#E1BA18" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="1.5" IsHitTestVisible="False" MinHeight="24" MaxWidth="267" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock Text="This is some warning message." Foreground="White" Margin="8,3,8,3" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=WarningIcon, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="fadeInStoryboard">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.15" Storyboard.TargetName="InformationBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeInStoryboard"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="fadeOutStoryBoard">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.15" Storyboard.TargetName="InformationBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Debug 1">
                <TextBox Height="80" Width="150" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Debug 2">
                <TextBox Height="80" Width="150" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### What is my problem exactly?

What do we have here? I've applied the `Style` to two `TextBox`es in a `TabControl`.

On the first `TabItem` (Debug 1), the IsMouseOver trigger works just fine and fades the warning message in and out.

However, an identical `TextBox` on the second `TabItem` (Debug 2) throws the following error and the IsMouseOver trigger isn't working at all.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=WarningIcon'. BindingExpression:Path=IsMouseOver; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

### What have I tried to solve the problem?

As I read some suggested solutions on how to fix this, I finally noticed that **all** of the following triggers are **working fine**:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=WarningIcon, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="InformationBorder" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
</DataTrigger>
```

--

```
<Trigger SourceName="WarningIcon" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="fadeInStoryboard">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.15" Storyboard.TargetName="InformationBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeInStoryboard"/>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="fadeOutStoryBoard">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.15" Storyboard.TargetName="InformationBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

--

```
<Trigger SourceName="WarningIcon" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="InformationBorder" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
</Trigger>
```

This error only occurs when I use a `DataTrigger` with two `Storyboard`s in a `TabControl`, but why?
I already know **how** to fix this, so I'm just interested **what**'s happening behind the scenes.